# Sequelize where statement with today's date

Tags: sequelize.js

i'm using sequelize in my backend and i'm trying to query for data containing a date attribute that matches today's date.
I am trying right not with:

```
where: { date: { [Op.eq]: new Date() } },
```

But i'm getting null as a result, I fetched all data and there are in total 3 instances where date is today's date.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further googling, i found a nice way to do it. My problem was that the dates stored where midnight hours. So i only had to do this:

```
  let today = new Date();
  today.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

and then query for date: { [Op.eq]: today }.